# Javascript; Compress array with distinct values/count

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, distinct

I got myself a puzzle i'm working on. I got a multi-dimensional array in Javascript that looks like this;
Each feature has an ID, a date(string) and a state

For example;

```
Features = [
    [1, "20200503", "Active"],
    [2, "20200503", "Closed"],
    [2, "20200503", "Closed"],
    [2, "20200502", "Closed"],
    [2, "20200501", "Active"],
    [2, "20200430", "Active"],
    [2, "20200430", "Active"],
    [3, "20200503", "New"],
    [3, "20200502", "New"],
];
```

I want to compress this array into a new one where I want this as a result;

```
Features = [
    [1, 1, "Active"],
    [2, 3, "Closed"],
    [2, 3, "Active"],
    [3, 2, "New"],
];
```

I would like to do a distinct on the ID and the state and count the date.

Is it somehow possible to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is `reduce` the array into a smaller one. Well, there is a function for that! You can pass an empty array as the second argument of the reduce function to use that as an accumulator, and compare the cursor with the previous element in order to find out what to do with it.

```
features = features.reduce((acc, cur, index, arr) => {
  let prev = arr[index - 1];

  if (index === 0 || cur[0] !== prev[0] || cur[2] !== prev[2]) acc.push([cur[0], 1, cur[2]]);
  else acc[acc.length - 1][1]++;

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function compress(features) {
    // First get unique Ids and states
    var ids = new Set(features.map(f => f[0]);
    var states = new Set(features.map(f => f[2]);

    // Array in which we will store the result
    const result = [];

    // Next loop through to make every permutation for the IDs and States 
    for (const id of ids) {
        for (const state of states) {
            // Get number of features with id and state
            let featureCount = features.filter(f => f[0] === id && f[2] === state).length;
            
            // check if there are any with ID "id" and State "state"
            if (featureCount > 0)
                result.push([id, featureCount, state]);
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Then call it like this

```
var compressedFeatures = compress(Features);
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to work, thanks! But there is one more issue; what if I add more values to my array I to compress;
For example: 

`[1, "20200503", "Jim", "Active"]`
`[1, "20200503", "John", "Active"]`
`[1, "20200503, "John", "Active"]`

Is there a way to count the date as well as the name?